# counting number of observations in MySQL by 15 minute intervals

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as numRecords, 
                ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SqlUnixTime)/(15 * 60))  AS timeStamp 
            from myDB.myTABLE GROUP BY timeStamp WHERE SqlUnixTime > '1508618097';
```

I already have SqlUnixTime in my database. What I would like is a table that shows something like:

```
 timeStamp numRecords   
1   1676320        116 
2   1676321         80 
3   1676322         70 
4   1676323         78 
5   1676324        138 
6   1676325         44
```

I think I'm close but now sure where I am making the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be something like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SqlUnixTime)/(15 * 60)) AS timeStamp,
      COUNT(*) as numRecords
FROM myDB.myTABLE
WHERE SqlUnixTime > 1508618097
GROUP BY timeStamp;
```

I would use `FLOOR()` instead of `ROUND()`.

Comment: Doesn't like it -- shows the first line as an error. Also, this db is large so is there a way to have the where apply first to execute faster?

Comment: Removing the "," after timeStamp I get just one result: ' # timeStamp, numRecords
'0', '3144114''